# Azure Log Analytics - Query to get the logged in user info

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am a newie to Azure log analytics and dashboards.
We are looking to build a dashboard with log analytics query in Azure. We need to show different views to people based on the user logged in to Azure. For this we need to get the current logged in user so that we can pass this as a variable in the query. How can I achieve this.

I searched for this in the help documents. But nowhere there is a mention on how to get the logged-in user

Comment: What do you man by logged in users to Azure ? Are you looking for Azure subscription or VM. Can you give more clarity ?

Comment: The goal is , to show the dashboard only to managers and that too is restricted by who logs in. The manager who logs in should be able to see only his reportee's data. That is the intention. For that, we need to get the logged-in user info to apply sucha filter in the query

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/azure-active-directory-meets-power-bi/

Power BI + Azure AD integration. In case you need, you can extend and create your own queries to retrieve more information from other data sources (e.g Azure Monitor)

Comment: We are using Tableau in our organisation.

Comment: then, you'll need to code something in the middle to get the token from Azure AD, grab the data and push it to tableau